# Re-partition a LVM partitionin that has /home mount on it

Tags: linux, partition, lvm

I know this question maybe very elementary in nature, so if someone can show me a guide to do it and think this thread is repetitive, please edit it at your convenience. 
I found out that on my Redhat system, the `/home` is mounted on a LVM with a xfs file system on `/dev/mapper/rhel_home/` partition that is about 200GB in size. The problem is now that I want to separate this partition into 4 50GB large partitions and mount `/home` on one of them and mount some other directory on the other partitions. How do I go to do that? I can't use `gparted`, so I'd prefer to do it though the shell.

here is the result of the command:

```
[root@localhost ~]# vgdisplay -v
    Using volume group(s) on command line.
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               rhel
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  4
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                3
  Open LV               3
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               232.34 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              59479
  Alloc PE / Size       59463 / 232.28 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       16 / 64.00 MiB
  VG UUID               400oqQ-ClvP-Vdmi-D8Nh-ib4t-Knhs-fAhPjP

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/rhel/swap
  LV Name                swap
  VG Name                rhel
  LV UUID                b9IZNi-zMmG-angt-slI7-WYIg-0pJZ-bOARHT
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time localhost.localdomain, 2016-09-21 09:58:47 -0700
  LV Status              available
  # open                 2
  LV Size                15.75 GiB
  Current LE             4032
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     8192
  Block device           253:1

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/rhel/home
  LV Name                home
  VG Name                rhel
  LV UUID                LoxHKf-atFU-Q246-cfMq-3ToY-o0jX-POnZg0
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time localhost.localdomain, 2016-09-21 09:58:48 -0700
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                166.53 GiB
  Current LE             42631
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     8192
  Block device           253:2

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/rhel/root
  LV Name                root
  VG Name                rhel
  LV UUID                eQdCo3-fPr0-Nh0y-8HAy-VBEE-uZyr-3qBsSs
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time localhost.localdomain, 2016-09-21 09:58:50 -0700
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                50.00 GiB
  Current LE             12800
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     8192
  Block device           253:0

  --- Physical volumes ---
  PV Name               /dev/sda2     
  PV UUID               JGq039-2zfz-RJms-UI20-xVM9-R0xZ-LfRQ7S
  PV Status             allocatable
  Total PE / Free PE    59479 / 16
```

Comment: http://blog.endpoint.com/2015/01/shrink-xfs-partition-almost-possible.html

Comment: Could you also add the output of `df -h`. Maybe /home is small enough to copy it to your root partition temporarily. Otherwise you need another disk or backup on a remote machine.

Comment: Depending how much space /home is using you could reformat the swap volume or roll everything in /home up into a tarball in /root

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to *split* the logical volume (LV) `/dev/mapper/rhel_home`. You could shrink it to 50G and then create 3 other LVs (each 50G).

But before shrinking the original LV you would need to shrink it's file system.
This is **not possible with XFS**. If you still have unused space on your volume group (VG) then you could simply add a new LV, copy files to the new LV and remove the original one.

Check the output of `vgdisplay` for unused space (Free  PE). If not then you need to add another HD temporarily to get your task done.